# WPF Binding: How to prevent target update when source value does not change after input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

In `TextBox` binding with a converter I am experiencing a problem: when the user changes the text, the value flows not only to the source, but always also back into the UI - also in cases when the converted value is exactly the same as before the input, i.e. source value does not change.

Can this be prevented?

My scenario is this: I want the user to input a space-separated list of academic titles that are represented by numeric values from a codelist in my model. The problem occurs after there is a valid title and the user presses space in order to be able to write a second title - since the converter is tolerant of spaces, "TITLE1 " is converted to exactly the same number as "TITLE1", but since an update of the target is triggered, the textbox input changes back to "TITLE1", effectively preventing the user to add any further input.

The model value is a `String`, XAML binding is this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Model.TitleValuesDelimitedString" Delay="500"
             Converter="{StaticResource TitleValuesDelimitedStringToDisplayStringConv}" 
             ConverterParameter="{x:Static local:UICodeLists.TitleCodeList}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
         <vrules:TitlesSpaceSeparated />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Notes:

- the source property is a simple POCO property, but I've also tried to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a way that it does not fire when value does not change, with no success
- the behavior is observed also when doing an explicit update source on the binding (`UpdateSourceProperty=Explicit` + `UpdateSource()`)

UPDATE: Converter code:

```
public class TitleValuesDelimitedStringToDisplayStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ciselnik = parameter as Ciselnik;
        var skrDelimitedList = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(skrDelimitedList))
            return null;

        var skrList = new List<string>();
        Person.ApplyDelimitedString(skrList, skrDelimitedList);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var skr in skrList)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            sb.Append(ciselnik.FindBySkratka(skr).DisplayName);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ciselnik = parameter as Ciselnik;
        var input = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return Person.CreateDelimitedString(new string[0]);

        List<string> skrList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var titul in input.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (ciselnik.ContainsDisplayName(titul))
                skrList.Add(ciselnik.FindByDisplayName(titul).Skratka);
        }
        return Person.CreateDelimitedString(skrList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it in a more simplified sample and had the same behaviour. Would you post your converter code so we can think about a workaround.

Comment: @christoph: I posted the converter code. `Ciselnik` class is responsible for resolving the value for a display name and vice versa; static methods of the `Person` class are essentially string split/join operations...

Comment: If I understand you correctly: The user enters something like "34 12" and while he is still typing the number codes shall be replaced by academic titles? Is that correct?

Comment: No, the user works with human-readable titles (like "Ing. PhD"), while the model works with a space-delimited number string (like "34 12").

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I´m working on an update for my answer.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`. The default will be applied that is `LostFocus`.

If a single source update on losing focus doesn´t suit your needs you could compare the trimmed versions of your private `TitleValuesDelimitedString` field and the value within the setter. If those are alike don´t raise `PropertyChanged`. Try something like this:

```
    private string titleValuesDelimitedString;
    public string TitleValuesDelimitedString
    {
        get { return titleValuesDelimitedString; }
        set
        {
            string fieldComparable = this.titleValuesDelimitedString ?? string.Empty;
            string valueComparable = value ?? string.Empty;

            if (fieldComparable.Trim() != valueComparable.Trim())
            {
                this.titleValuesDelimitedString = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("TitleValuesDelimitedString");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I edited your converter like this:

```
public class TitleValuesDelimitedStringToDisplayStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string latestValueSendToSource = null;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ciselnik = parameter as Ciselnik;
        var skrDelimitedList = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(skrDelimitedList))
            return null;

        var skrList = new List<string>();
        Person.ApplyDelimitedString(skrList, skrDelimitedList);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var skr in skrList)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append(' ');
            sb.Append(ciselnik.FindBySkratka(skr).DisplayName);
        }
        string goingToSendToTarget = sb.ToString();

        if (this.latestValueSendToSource != null && this.latestValueSendToSource.Trim().Equals(goingToSendToTarget)
        {
            return this.latestValueSendToSource;
        }
        else
        {
            return goingToSendToTarget;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var ciselnik = parameter as Ciselnik;
        var input = value as string;
        this.latestValueSendToSource = input;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return Person.CreateDelimitedString(new string[0]);



        List<string> skrList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var titul in input.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (ciselnik.ContainsDisplayName(titul))
                skrList.Add(ciselnik.FindByDisplayName(titul).Skratka);
        }

        return Person.CreateDelimitedString(skrList);
    }
}
```

Note the usage of the variable `latestValueSendToSource`. For that to not lead to unexpected behaviour you should make clear the binding gets its own instance of the converter:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Model.TitleValuesDelimitedString" Delay="500"              
         ConverterParameter="{x:Static local:UICodeLists.TitleCodeList}"
         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
     <vrules:TitlesSpaceSeparated />
  </Binding.ValidationRules>
  <Binding.Converter>
      <local:TitleValuesDelimitedStringToDisplayStringConverter />
  </Binding.Converter>
</Binding>
```

Hope that suits your needs.

Comment: `LostFocus` does not suit my needs, since this way I don't see invalid input immediately. Regardning `PropertyChanged`: what's strange is that I don't fire it currently at all (I'm binding to a plain property), and even in this case the conversion back happens.